# Как выполнить GET запрос средствами PHP?

Tags: php, get

Как сделать GET запрос на PHP? Скажем, мне надо сделать такой запрос:

```
index.php?host=[host]&port=[port]
```

Как такой запрос осуществить? А то я как не пытаюсь, запрос не выходит.

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса: вам надо осуществить переход (сформировать ссылку) по этой ссылке из скрипта или обработать входящую ссылку такого вида?

Comment: как вариант: curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый тупой и не самый правильный способ.

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://host.tld/index.php?host=[host]&port=[port]');
```

Если вы вдруг собрались вызывать тот сайт, на котором располагается этот скрипт, то предлагаю обсудить здесь необходимость данного действия.

Answer (score 3):

Если доступно расширение **php-curl**, можно отправить запрос так

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://httpbin.org/get?qwe=rty&a=qqq');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $out;
```